# Can't compile Wine under Windows

Tags: cygwin, wine

I need to compile wine dlls under windows for debug purposes.

I installed cygwin, downloaded wine and run "./configure", then following error appears. I am completely new to Linux environment, so I can even understand what it does mean.

```
./configure: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
261414951 [main] sh 1368 fhandler_dev_zero::fixup_mmap_after_fork: requested 0x7E6E0000 != 0x0 mem alloc base 0x0, state 0x10000, size 524288, Win32 error 487
261415207 [main] sh 1368 C:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - recreate_mmaps_after_fork_failed
261415593 [main] sh 1368 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [Cygwin wiki](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall), errors related to `fork()` are usually solved by rebasing.

Stop all Cygwin services; open a command prompt & issue:

```
\cygwin\bin\dash -c '/usr/bin/rebaseall'
```